# Is it idiomatic to say "Your toy is mixed into the pile (of toys)"?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

Let's say your child had a lot of toys and all the toys were piled up into a messy pile.

Now you want to find a specific toy in that pile.

Is it idiomatic to say "**Your toy is mixed into the pile (of toys)**"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can say "Your toy is somewhere in there (in the pile of toys)" or "Your toy is in there somewhere"

Comment: Simple and easy to understand!

Comment: "Your toy is in there somewhere" feels like a more natural word order to me. The second sentence doesn't sound natural at all. Maybe "Your toy is mixed in with the others in that pile."

Comment: @TypeIA It may not be natural but it is well understood. With the first sentence I find either word order comfortable and natural.

Comment: @SovereignSun Certainly it would be understood, but the asker specifically asked for _idiomatic_ statements.

Comment: In this case anything with "mixed" sounds unnatural to me.

Comment: In some similar situations, Could we say "She is in the library somewhere" or "She is somewhere around here" or  "She is around somewhere"?

Comment: @Tom Yes, while **somewhere** doesn't give out the exact location, the borders are determined by a predefined area **"the library"** for instance. But notice that although "She is around somewhere" is grammatically correct it carries a deeply philosophical meaning which can go beyond borders of known space. She can be a mile away, or on the other end of the galaxy, or even in the realm of the dead.